# Sublime 3 backspace strange behaviour in Twig tags (Removes letter before and after cursor)

Tags: sublimetext3

How can I disable this backspace behavior and remove letters in strandard way?
[image]

Comment: What packages or plugins do you have installed?

Answer (score -1):

For some reasons in `Sublime Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` were changed backspace hotkey actions. I didn't add new plugins or macroses. Probably some kind of bug.
I did next steps to fix it:

1. Input `sublime.log_commands(True)`
2. Press backspace and check what happens. I seen this wrong command that added in file for unknown reason: `command: run_macro_file {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Delete Left Right.sublime-macro"}`
3. Open `Preferences -> Key Bindings` input standard backspace action by command: `{ "keys": ["backspace"], "command": "left_delete" },`

Comment: Why -1 reputation ? What I said wrong ? :) Lol